# Joining python list at a delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have python list, say for example:

```
list = ['|','angela','demario','|','|','david','lucia','|','|','michael','jackson','|']
```

I want the output list to be:

```
output_list = ['angela demario', 'david lucia', 'michael jackson']
```

so how can i use delimiter '|' to split and then join the list and get the output i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join on whitespace and then split on your delimiter. The rest is just cleanup to remove empty strings from your result.

```
[*filter(None, map(str.strip, ' '.join(yourlist).split('|')))] 
# ['angela demario', 'david lucia', 'michael jackson']
```

Comment: How about `' '.join(d).strip('| ').split(' | | ')` ?

Comment: @JonClements Hi! That's a nice one, but assumes that the delimiter is always "| |". Which may or may not be enough here given limited context. Also treats spaces very literally.

Comment: @KaranNayak: Be a nice Stackoverflower and accept the answer if it helped you (green tick on the left).

Comment: @Jan ++ for your equally helpful answer!

Comment: @cs95: Thanks but mine looks a bit crippled compared to your and Jon's one-liner solutions...

Answer (score 1):

You could write yourself a little generator function:

```
lst = ['|','angela','demario','|','|','david','lucia','|','|','michael','jackson','|']

def make_list(iterable):
    stack, collect = [list(), False]
    for item in iterable:
        if item == "|" and not collect:
            collect = True
        elif item == "|" and collect:
            yield " ".join(stack)
            stack, collect = [list(), False]
        elif collect is not False:
            stack.append(item)

    if stack:
        yield " ".join(stack)


output_list = [item for item in make_list(lst)]
print(output_list)
# ['angela demario', 'david lucia', 'michael jackson']
```

Letting everything else beside, calling your variable `list` is always a bad idea.

Comment: Or... you can take advantage of `itertools.groupby` and do: `[' '.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(d, lambda L: L == '|') if not k]`

Comment: thank you guys for answering my question, but please check the cs95's response, that worked for me!!

Comment: @JonClements: Sweet :-)